# Re["Complex Exponential"] does not return Cosine

Tags: functions, complex

I am having some problems retrieving the real part of a complex function. I have a function which looks as follows:

$$ 2^{-\dfrac{4\left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{z}{\sqrt{2}} \right)^{2}}{w^2}     } e^{-i\left(\dfrac{k*x}{\sqrt{2}}-\dfrac{k*z}{\sqrt{2}} +\phi+\omega t    \right)}  $$

Basically, I am only interested in the real part of this function. Thus the complex exponential part would turn into a Cosine function with the same argument. However, if I apply the $Re[\ ]$ operator onto this function I get:

$$ Re[2^{-\dfrac{4\left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{z}{\sqrt{2}} \right)^{2}}{w^2}     } e^{-i\left(\dfrac{k*x}{\sqrt{2}}-\dfrac{k*z}{\sqrt{2}} +\phi+\omega t    \right)} ] $$

I understand that I could just manually replace the complex exponential with a cosine but that would not be functional for my calculation program. Is there any way in which I can do this consistently and automatically?

The raw code looks as follows:

```
VectorValues = {E01x -> 0, E01y -> 1, E01z -> 0, E02x -> 0, 
   E02y -> 1, E02z -> 0, K1x -> Sin[θ/2] k, K1y -> 0, 
   K1z -> Cos[θ/2] k, K2x -> -Sin[θ/2] k, K2y -> 0, 
   K2z -> Cos[θ/2] k, B01x -> -Sin[θ/2], B01y -> 0, 
   B01z -> Cos[θ/2], B02x -> Cos[θ/2], B02y -> 0, 
   B02z -> Sin[θ/2]};

E01 = {E01x, E01y, E01z} //. VectorValues;
E02 = {E02x, E02y, E02z} //. VectorValues;
B01 = {B01x, B01y, B01z} //. VectorValues;
B02 = {B02x, B02y, B02z} //. VectorValues;
K1 = {K1x, K1y, K1z} //. VectorValues;
K2 = {K2x, K2y, K2z} //. VectorValues;
r = {x, y, z} //. VectorValues;


E1b = E01* Exp[-I (ω t0 - K1.r + ϕ)]*Exp[-((4 Log[2]*(-x*Sin[θ/2] + z*Cos[θ/2])^2)/w0^2)];

B1b = B01* Exp[-I (ω t0 - K1.r + ϕ)]*Exp[-((4 Log[2]*(-x*Sin[θ/2] + z*Cos[θ/2])^2)/w0^2)];

S1 = 1/μ0 (Re[E1b]\[Cross]Re[B1b]);

S1vec [x_, y_, z_, t0_] = S1 //. {θ -> -π/2};

S1vec[x, y, z, t][[1]]
```

Where `S1vec [x_, y_, z_, t0_]` is a vector containing 3 equations of which the part above (latex code) is a small part.

Comment: please post the Mathematica input lines. We are very lazy people here who prefer copy-paste. And try using `Simplify[...,Assumptions->Elements[{x,z,kx,kz},Reals]`.

Comment: @Sumit Thank you for your suggestion, I added the code, hope it helps to clarify what I mean. The Simplify expression including the assumption statement still does not work and the output remains the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your final expression is already `Re[]`

```
ComplexExpand[S1vec[x, y, z, t][[1]]]
```

> $\frac{2^{-\frac{8
>    \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{z}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2}{\text{w0}^2}-\frac{
>    1}{2}} \cos ^2\left(\frac{k x}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{k z}{\sqrt{2}}+t \omega
>    +\phi \right)}{\text{$\mu $0}}$